# I want to change the player_head.json in minecraft, how I can do it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm making a map and a resource pack for it. I want to make a Zombie with a 3D model on his head, and I think I can change the player_head.json, but I don't find the original .json model in the resource pack. Can anyone help me find the path of it?

Answer (score 1):

C:\Users\yourname\whereyouputit\nameofpack\assets\minecraft\models\block\skull.json

That should be where the path for the skull is.